# How can I change the expression x1 to x[1] in a simple way?

Tags: replacement, pattern-matching, rule

I have one expression,

```
exp0=x1+x9/8+ x4 x5
```

I want to get

```
exp1=x[1]+x[9]/8+x[4] x[5]
```

Is there a very simple way to do that?

Comment: this looks like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)  ;)   Why not just use indexed variables in first place then? what is it exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: @Nasser I do not think that it qualifies as an XY problem. A question is described, and the author of the OP just asks for a solution. Not to check a proposed solution. Maybe I am missing something though.

Answer (score 11):

I added `xy` to `exp0` just to prove there's no `xy` problem :) as well as a two-digit index:

```
exp0 = x1 + x9/8 + x4 x5 + xy + x15;
exp0 /. s_Symbol :> 
  With[{xn = StringSplit[SymbolName[s], 
      n : DigitCharacter.. :> ToExpression@n]},
   x[Last@xn] /; MatchQ[xn, {"x", _Integer}]
   ]
(*  xy + x[1] + x[4] x[5] + x[9]/8 + x[15]  *)
```

Comment: I burst into laughter when I saw the `xy` comment

Comment: @bmf Tee-hee. Really, it's what attracted me to answer.

Comment: I like answers that have pedagogical as well as recreational value. Thumbs up!!!

Answer (score 8):

One way to do it:

```
xi = Table[Symbol["x" <> ToString@i], {i, 10}];
xii = Table[x[i], {i, 1, 10}];
rule = Thread[xi -> xii];

exp0 /. rule
```

> [image: list]

Answer (score 6):

```
Clear[toindexed]
toindexed[expr_, v_Symbol] := toindexed[expr, {v}]
toindexed[expr_, lst_] := 
 With[{patt = Alternatives @@ ToString /@ lst}, 
  StringReplace[ToString@InputForm@expr, 
  var : patt ~~ i : DigitCharacter .. :> var ~~ "[" ~~ i ~~ "]"] // ToExpression]
```

Usage:

```
toindexed[exp0, x]
(* x[1] + x[4] x[5] + x[9]/8 *)

toindexed[x1 y2 z3 + y4^z5/x6, {x, y, z}]
(* y[4]^z[5]/x[6] + x[1] y[2] z[3] *)
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `SequenceReplace`

```
index[f_] :=
 Module[{o},
  o = Characters[ToString @ InputForm @ f];
  o = SequenceReplace[o, {x_?LetterQ, y_} :> x <> "[" <> y <> "]"];
  ToExpression @ StringJoin @ o]
```

2 examples:

```
index[x1 + x9/8 + x4 x5]
```

[image]

```
index[a1 + b3 / c9]
```

[image]

To keep things simple I didn't consider indexes greater than 9.

Answer (score 2):

Using `Cases` to obtain all independent variables:

```
index[expr_] /; Length@CharacterCounts[ToString[expr]] >= 2 && 
                  AllTrue[Rest@Characters@ToString@expr, DigitQ] := 
Times @@ (expr /. x_ :> MapThread[#1@#2 &, 
  List /@ StringJoin /@ SplitBy[Characters[ToString[x]], LetterQ]])

index[expr_] := Module[{vars, ivars},
      vars = Cases[Function[x, Cases[x, _Symbol, Depth[x]]]@expr, 
             x_ /; Length@CharacterCounts[ToString[x]] >= 2 && 
             AllTrue[Rest@Characters@ToString@x, DigitQ]];
     ivars = Flatten@Function[x, MapThread[
             If[Length@CharacterCounts[ToString[x]] >= 2 && 
             AllTrue[Rest@Characters@ToString@x, DigitQ], #1@#2 &, 
    Nothing], List /@ ToExpression /@ StringJoin /@ 
    SplitBy[Characters[ToString[x]], LetterQ]], Listable]@vars;
    expr /. Thread[vars -> ivars]]
```

Testing `index`:

```
index[exp0]
```

[image]

```
index[a1 + b11/c9]
```

[image]

This implementation isn't that simple, but I considered indexes greater than 9.